# How to border a text using Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently making my first "About me" website that would suit my portfolio since I'm going to apply for my first IT job next week. I was advised to create it using Bootstrap and I'm wondering: is there any bootstrap ready component that allows to border a text nicely to make it look more professional?

It should look like a centered box with border and the text should be centered within. I attach an IMG showing the exact thing I'm looking for.

I think I'd be able to do it in CSS but my tutor said it's Bootstrap doable. I couldn't find it in the documentation however, tried to search using "bordered text", "text in box" etc. but nothing shows up.

Any help appreciated.

[What I'd love to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PeFe0.png)

**Forget to mention the code**

Thank you for your help!

And I'm really sorry guys. I forgot to add my own code. Here's my effort (it's supposed to be a section about my journalist career):

```
<div class="journalism">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <h3>Journalism</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

As for the CSS:

```
.container {
    height: 50vh;
}

.row {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.journalism {
    margin: 0;
    background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/518543/pexels-photo-518543.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940");
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    filter: sepia();
}
```

I'm also trying to do the same but with an IMG as the background.

Comment: First you should to give your effort !  if there is any issue then we will help.

Comment: @Lukasz which version of bootstrap are you using??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**However you haven't given any code. Which is really a bad practice.
Kindly post some of your code. first then ask for help.**

---

Hello I don't know what amount of Bootstrap solution you want.

**I tried my best to fully depend on bootstrap.**

**UPDATED**:: `fieldset` class for the background. In this case you have to change the text color also for the better readability.

Hope this is what you want.

Let's have try...

```
 <head>
   <style >
       fieldset{
          background: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/518543/pexels-photo-518543.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940");
          background-repeat:no-repeat;
          background-position:center;
          background-size:cover;
}
       p#innerPara{padding:20px ;}
       legend{width:200px;padding:10px 20px;}
    </style>
 </head>

 <body>

  <div class='container'>
   <div class="col-lg-6">
     <fieldset class="border" >
       <legend class ='text-center'>About Us</legend>


         <p id="innerPara">
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and 
            typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
            standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown 
             printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type
              specimen book. It has survived not only five 
             centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, 
             remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised 
             in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing 
             Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop 
             publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including 
             versions of Lorem Ipsum.

       </p>
 </fieldset>
 </div>
```

**MyOutput**
**If any confusion ask in comment.**

[image]

[image]

Comment: kindly update me back if solved your problem. Don't post your code as answer just use `Edit` button `below the question` to update the question. i am updating your question.

Comment: Yes, the problem is solved. Thank you for your help and sorry for mistakes. I'm still learning how to move on this forum. Is there anything else I should do to close this thread?

Comment: What a great and simple solution, thank you for sharing it!

Answer (score 0):

It's using html, css not specific to bootstrap. Below is the sample

```css
hr{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
}

span{
  width: 100px !important;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

#container{
  width: 510px;
  height: 100px;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0 !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
    <hr>
    <span> about </span>
    <hr>
    <div id="container"></div>
```